# Using JavaScript to overlay multiple images in Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gis

I am wondering if there is a simple way to overlay images in Google Maps using JavaScript and 4 coordinate points. I've seen it done with three points but that doesn't work when your maps sit a bit diagonal on the landscape. I plan to build a database that will have fields for each of the points and links for each of the image files.

Any advice, code or resources that any of you could suggest would be very appreciated. :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use GrondOverlay

from google dev

> ```
>        historicalOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
>         'https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
>         imageBounds);
>     historicalOverlay.setMap(map);
> ```

see this link for a working sample https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple

or overlay maptype image

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image-overlay